# Create a form on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Greeting

I have a problem, I would like to create a form on wordpress manually but I cannot attach a php file to my wordpress page.

How to do ?

Comment: All your WordPress files are php files. You can write the php code on the page file you want to create a form on.

Comment: I believe you might have a problem on Apache or any server you are using, please state the error message or address more information.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this.

1. Create a child-theme from your theme and then create an individual template for the form (https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/). If the form is a page, then just copy the page.php file to the childtheme, renamte ist to page-form.php and then edit it. See https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/ for more information. Afterwards you can change the template in wordpress. Do not forget to sanitize form inputs (https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/theme-security/data-sanitization-escaping/)
2. Install a form plugin
   This is the solution I would prefer if your usecase allows this. I am using wpforms, but I have not checked for alternative plugins the last two years. There may be others that could work for you better.

Answer (score 0):

Create a shortcode for the PHP code, then paste the shortcode on the page where you want to put the form.

Reference:

- https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/